# NiFi: Configuring SSLContextService for GetHTTP or InvokeHTTP

Tags: get, apache-nifi

I am trying to use WMATA's (the DC system) Metro API, and use NiFi to pull in [some live Train Position data](https://developer.wmata.com/docs/services/). I currently have tried to use both `GetHTTP` and `InvokeHTTP`, but no luck. My confusion comes from two areas:

1) How to configure the processor itself?

2) Configuring the `SSLContextService`?

The Metro website gives a Primary and Secondary key - but I'm not sure how to parse that information, when the `SSLContextDriver` config asks for KeyStore filename, etc.

My `GetHTTP` config:

[image]

And my `SSL` config:

[image]

I get errors when I run the `GetHTTP` processor:
[image]

I hope my issue makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the specific error message you have show, the URL you specified has contentType={contentType} which is invalid. If you wanted to reference a flow file attribute, or variable, it would need to be ${contentType}. Otherwise if you really want to literally pass {contentType} then I think you would need to URL encode the brackets first.

For your SSL Context service, I believe in this case you want to set the truststore to CA certs instead of the keystore. It is similar to how your browser has truststores and verifies server identities when you go to an https page. You would only specify the keystore if you needed the GetHttp/InvokeHttp processor to also provide an identity so the other server could verify the identity of the processor.

Comment: For your first paragraph - do you mean put the entire url in `${ }`, or just the `{contentType}`? And I'm not sure if the server has to ID the other server... but if I just do Truststore, do I just move the location that is currently in Keystore? I appreciate the help

Comment: I moved over to Truststore... but got this error from my `GetHTTP`: `ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.GetHTTP GetHTTP[id=d5491dba-4ba9-1624-ee1b-93b065fbf6b9] received status code 401:Access Denied from https://api.wmata.com/TrainPositions/TrainPositions?contentType=`

Comment: I was referring just to {contentType} because it looked like you were trying to reference a variable. If you are not referencing a dynamic content type, then just put the real content type like contentType=application/json or something.

Comment: A 401 means you are not allowed to make the request that you tried to make, likely because you need to provide some kind of authentication to the service ... a username/password or API token or something so they can tell who you are.

Comment: The website literally gives the URL with the {contentType} attached to the end, so I just copy/pasted. The website also gives me a Primary & Secondary key, so I figure those are the API tokens? I just have no idea how to input those two keys

Comment: How would you input the keys if you were issuing a curl command, or using your browser?

Comment: Regarding the content type, their docs show that it is a parameter meant to be either json or xml - https://developer.wmata.com/docs/services/5763fa6ff91823096cac1057/operations/5763fb35f91823096cac1058

Comment: Yeah, apologies, still new at this. And I mean in my NiFi processor - I tried saving the primary key to a `.pem` file and converting it with the openssl tool, but turns out it's not a cert (which I guess makes sense). I just can't figure out how to get access with my GetHTTP processor and SSLContextService, and I've pointed Keystore Filename to the right place

Comment: Eg, this is the Primary Key: `5bcf1f7d091f4f618f1eefbefe23a56e`